# keeping 2 tables with 2 identical columns in sync

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Okay So I am relatively new to excel but have worked with mysql databases alot over the years I'm looking for a way to have a master table which is basically a master schedule sort of like so

```
    |  LOT  | task1 | task2 | task3 | task4 | task 5 |
    |   3   |mar-10 | mar-12| mar-15| mar-19|  mar-20|
    |   7   |mar-16 | mar-18| mar-22| mar-25|  mar-28|
```

and i basically want on a seperate tables to be automatically generated based on above table:

```
    |  LOT   |other info| task1 |
    |    3   |    bla   |mar-10 |
    |    7   |    bffd  |mar-16 |


    |  LO T  |  other   | task2 | 
    |    3   |  this    | mar-12|
    |    7   |  that    | mar-18|
```

This seems like It should be really easy to do but from what Ive deemed its not possible with a pivot table It should some how be possible with data relationships im guessing but can't figure out exactly how

any help or insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: And why aren't you using MS Access and applying a QUERY table then?

Comment: cause I need Multiple people to be able to edit the master t5able and getting them to not use excel will not be an acceptable answer as the new young guy

Comment: Ah, been there done that. I actually "Teched" my way out of a job like this over a decade ago at a local City job. I used my expertise in programming and created algorithms to do mundane tasks in Excel. The boss held a meeting where I demonstrated how to use my "auto-forms" in Excel... I was laid off two weeks later.

Comment: Excel is so easy to use and everyone wants it to be a database, but it's not. Have you tried to just simply creating two new tabs (sheets) and inserting a direct link from task1 for new tab1, and links to taks2 in new tab2, and so forth? With a link, any info changed in the master will auto update the new tabs. Or you could do it the other way around, where each task updates the master. Then links in master pointing to tab tasks.

Comment: Try out the solution I provided and let me know if this suits your needs.

Comment: ive never "links" i will definitely be looking into it thanks

Comment: I updated the solution. A link in Excel: enter the `=` symbol, then click on the sheet/tab, click on the desired cell. This creates a direct link to the data of the cell and now will auto update -- depending on the direction of the link.

Comment: You have calendar data, why not just use Google Calendar or similar?  You can sync to cell phones, and etc.  Each task can have its own calendar, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend this is a query table.

- The Master Sheet, should be the first tab.
- Set up a new sheet (or tab) for each task and name the tab, to
  correspond to the task name.
- The Master, will directly link to each Task's task.

[image]

**Note:** Excel is smart. If you copy formula, in Master tab cell C2, and paste it to C3, or paste it to C3:C50, Excel will also link it to the matching offset in the sheet its linked to.

Or visa versa:

- The Master Sheet, should be the first tab.
- Set up a new sheet (or tab) for each task and name the tab, to
  correspond to the task name.
- The Tasks, will directly link to the Master tab.

[image]

Comment: This solution sort of works is it possible to extend it so that a change to the non master updates the master table as well?

Comment: @brendosthoughts Yes. You can do it either way. The top image shows updating the master will update each task. The bottom image demonstrates updating each task will update the master.

Comment: @brendosthoughts Excel is not a database, so you can't really just query each sheet and create a perfect order of chronologically ordered data on the master -- as would do a Query from a DB.

Comment: @brendosthoughts Well, if each task is done in order from top to bottom and the Master is pointing to the same tasks in that same order, then the Master will be in order. So what I stated above is half truth.

Comment: Okay thanks, Sorry for the late reply work got busy and i had ton leave this sit